# Solving a sum involving a distribution

Tags: summation

Can anyone help me solve this sum?

```
 p[x_,a_] := PDF[NormalDistribution[0,a], x];
  a[x_] := Exp[x];
  u[x_] := (a[x]/(a[x] + 1));
  wa[x_, t_] := ((t - 3)*a[x])^(u[x] + .02442);
 Sum[p[x, .5]*wa[x, t], {x, 0, Infinity}, {t, 0, 50}]
```

[image: Output]
For me it only gives back a symbolic output. But I would like to have the actual result.

Comment: You mean, a closed form? Do you have any justification that it even exists?

Comment: @corey979 Justification? what do you mean?

Comment: Do you have strong evidence that a closed form (e.g., the sum is convergent) exists (you didn't answer my first question, so I assume you want a closed form), or is it just an expression that you arrived at, threw it in MMA and just expect it to do wonders?

Comment: No I don't have any evidence.. I forgot to take that into account. I do hope it is closed form though. I didn't randomly throw in numbers, -but I always assumed it would converge. @corey979

Comment: I see. Well, first, you can't obtain a result other than numeric because you have inexact numbers in the formulas. E.g., `Sum[1./k^2, {k, 1, Infinity}]` yields `1.64493`, but if you change `1.` to `1`, you'll get $\pi^2/6$. Second, examine `Table[Plot[Evaluate@ReIm[p[x, .5]*wa[x, t]], {x, 0, 5}, 
   PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, PlotLegends -> {"Re", "Im"}, 
   PlotLabel -> "t = " <> ToString@t], {t, 
   Range[0, 10]~Join~{100}~Join~{1000}}] // FlipView`. For every `t`, the expression decays very quickly with `x`, so summing up to infinity is an overkill (...)

Comment: (...) Second (as a side note), the bigger the `t`, the greater the values of the real part of the function are. Finally, `NSum[p[x, .5]*wa[x, t], {x, 0, 3}, {t, 0, 50}]` gave me (after several seconds) `303.282 + 4.15345 I` - is that a result that satisfies you - the _actual result_ you are after? [Changing `{x, 0, 3}` to `{x, 0, 4}` doesn't change the result.]